# ASP MVC 5 can't connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

I have created a database on a domain from my webhost but I can't figure out how to connect with it from my ASP MVC 5 project. I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with the MySQL Data Provider installed. I use the Server Explorer in VS and then the option Add connection. Here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUIhE.png

The details are 100% correct, I tested them with a simple PHP script. Any ideas?

Comment: This isn't Classic ASP - amend the tags!

Comment: There could be dozens of causes, you need to provide more detail to your problem than just "can't connect". What error does it generate?

Comment: Does the database allow remote connections?

Comment: Sorry for the late response! The database allows remote connections and the error it gives is: 'unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Seems that the database indeed allowed remote connections, but therefore I had to use different credentials with a non-standard port number.